# API RestFul - Multiple filters

Tags: spring, rest, http

I am looking the best practice to filtering múltiples items with restful paradigm.

I could select many differents options for example :

MotherBoard : Asus ,Chipset:AMD970

MotherBoard: Asus,Chipset:AMD970,AMD990FX , Conectivity:Bluetooth

```
Motherboard
    Type
        Asus
        Gigabyte
        MSI
    Chipset
        AMD760G
        AMD 970
        AMD 990FX
    Conectivity
        Bluetooth
        WiFi
```

Now I have the following URL's but I am not sure about this...

```
GET /api/v1/items?filters={"type":["Asus"]};{"chipset":["AMD 970"]}

GET /api/v1/items?filters={"type":["Asus"]};{"chipset":["AMD 970","AMD990FX"]}

GET /api/v1/items?type=<type>&chipset=<chipset>&conectivity<conectivity>
```

But all items could be optionals and depend on the items that you have selected the URL increase or decrease , so if anyone could help to me I will be very gratefully.

PD : I am using Java to develop this api

Regards!

Comment: I vote for the last one.

Comment: I am looking information and I choose the last one .. but how could I said that the options are optional ?

Answer (score 0):

I like an RQL style approach.  It has worked well for me on numerous API implementations. See https://github.com/persvr/rql.

With RQL it might end up looking like:

GET /api/v1/items?type=Asus&or(eq(chipset, 'AMD'), eq(chipset, 'AMD990FX'))

I have a Java RQL implementation that overloads query string parsing and the available functions.  For example ?type=Asus could also be written ?eq(type, 'Asus').  I also found it useful to implement an "in()" function such as ?eq(type,Asus)&in(chipset, "AMD 970", "AMD990FX").

Comment: By the way, what server side language are you using?

Comment: I am using Java to develop this , but I am interesting to know the best practices for developing the api restful. :) .. all options are interesting to learn.